Is there a way to compile different predictor variables' data recorded separately for the same response variable?
In my data, I have the distribution of average monthly salary by age, sex and educational attainment. Each factor is recorded in separate cross-tables with salary. How can I compile the data so that I can examine the combined effect of this factors on the response variable. for example, the combined effect of educational attainment, age and sex on salary, which will be my R squared
I tried to examine the relationship between each predictor and response variable separately and I fear the bias nature of this. I want to examine the combined effect of the predictor variables on the response variable.
